# Swift way to get WIFI name wihtout using SystemConfiguration.CaptiveNetwork

Tags: ios, swift, wifi

I want to be able to get the name of the WIFI that the iOS device use in **Swift**. Since `SystemConfiguration.CaptiveNetwork` is deprecated I want to know if anyone have a good and working example (using `NetworkExtension` or whatever) for that.

Comment: It's an objective c example. I wonder if there is a swift one because I'm new in iOS in general

Comment: ok have a look this one please http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/78318/getting-wifi-ssid-on-ios-in-swift

Comment: Thank you but they use SystemConfiguration.CaptiveNetwork methods. It's now deprecated